# Форматирование полученных данных в jquery

Tags: jquery

Есть у меня маска для поля input

```
 $("#PHONE").mask("+7 (999) 999-99-99");
```

В итоге при передаче он передает так как записал, а мне нужно чтобы он отправлял в формате 9999999999   без +7 скобок и тире. Подскажите как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я помню, .mask ничего не передаёт, только форматирует значение инпута по маске. Задача сводится к подготовке значения перед отправкой на обработку.

```js
$("#phone").mask("+7 (999) 999-99-99");
$('.numeric').on('click', function () {
    var phone = $("#phone").val().replace(/\D/g, '').slice(1);
    console.log(phone);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
<input type="button" name="go" class="numeric" value="go" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно в обрабочике события `submit()`, для Вашей формы (id="form"), извлечь неотформатированное значение телефона и добавить его в параметры отправляемой формы "налету":

```
$("#form").submit(function () { 
    $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="raw_phone" value="' + $("#phone").cleanVal() + '" />');
});
```